# Mono.MoonException: invalid RuntimeVersion

Tags: mono

I have been trying to get Moonlight to work with a particular Web service, (http://viaplay.se), and after some research I got Moonlight working in both Google Chrome and Firefox.  However, when tryiing to play one of the streaming videos from the site nothing happens.  I started both browsers from a terminal window in the hopes of getting some useful debugging information.  Everything seems to work up until a RuntimeVersion check is performed, which is where it stops.  I am starting to think that it is due to the unfinished API of Silverlight 4 support, but I am not totally sure.  Hence why I have not filed it as a bug.  I have attached the output from both browsers when trying to stream a video from the site.  Any help or answer would be appreciated.

Google Chrome Output:

```
~]$ google-chrome 
Moonlight: 3.99.0.3
Moonlight: Attempting to load libmoonloaderxpi 
[1547:1568:1123/235224:ERROR:native_backend_gnome_x.cc(448)] Keyring save failed: 
Moonlight: 3.99.0.3
Moonlight: Attempting to load libmoonloaderxpi 
Moonlight: 3.99.0.3
Moonlight: Attempting to load libmoonloaderxpi 
debug_get_option: GALLIUM_DRIVER = softpipe
couldn't open libtxc_dxtn.so, software DXTn compression/decompression unavailable
Moonlight: Installing signal handlers for crash reporting.
Moonlight: Enabling MONO_DEBUG=keep-delegates,reverse-pinvoke-exceptions and        MOONLIGHT_ENABLE_CONSOLE=1
Moonlight: Loaded mscodecs from: /home/david/.mozilla/plugins/moonlight/silverlight-   media-pack-linux-x64-21-1.so.
Moonlight: browser bridge not found for your browser (likely not needed). User agent =  'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64  Safari/537.11'
Moonlight: Plugin AppDomain Creation: OK
Moonlight: 3.99.0.3
Moonlight: Attempting to load libmoonloaderxpi 
Moonlight: Shutting down
Moonlight: browser bridge not found for your browser (likely not needed). User agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11'
Moonlight: Plugin AppDomain Creation: OK
Moonlight: URL = http://viaplay.se/film/battle-of-los-angeles
Moonlight: URL = http://viaplay.se/assets/54bde6d6/ViasatPlayer.xap
Moonlight: OpenGL vendor string: Tungsten Graphics, Inc
Moonlight: OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) 965GM 
Moonlight: OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 8.0.4
Mono.MoonException: invalid RuntimeVersion
at System.Windows.Deployment.CompareRuntimeVersions () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Windows.Deployment.ReadManifest () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Windows.Deployment.InitializeDeployment (IntPtr plugin, System.String xapPath,    System.String culture, System.String uiCulture) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
Moonlight: ErrorEventArgs created with message: 'invalid RuntimeVersion'
EMIT OF EVENT Error(1) ON OBJECT Surface CALLED WITH NO LISTENERS AND NON-NULL CALLDATA
```

Firefox Output:

```
~]$ firefox
Moonlight: 3.99.0.3
Moonlight: Attempting to load libmoonloaderxpi 
debug_get_option: GALLIUM_DRIVER = softpipe
couldn't open libtxc_dxtn.so, software DXTn compression/decompression unavailable
Moonlight: Installing signal handlers for crash reporting.
Moonlight: Enabling MONO_DEBUG=keep-delegates,reverse-pinvoke-exceptions and    MOONLIGHT_ENABLE_CONSOLE=1
Moonlight: Loaded mscodecs from: /home/david/.mozilla/plugins/moonlight/silverlight-  media-pack-linux-x64-21-1.so.
Moonlight: browser bridge not found for your browser (likely not needed). User agent =  'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:15.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/15.0.1'
Moonlight: Plugin AppDomain Creation: OK
Moonlight: Shutting down
Moonlight: browser bridge not found for your browser (likely not needed). User agent =  'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:15.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/15.0.1'
Moonlight: Plugin AppDomain Creation: OK
Moonlight: URL = http://viaplay.se/film/battle-of-los-angeles
Moonlight: URL = http://viaplay.se/assets/54bde6d6/ViasatPlayer.xap
Moonlight: OpenGL vendor string: Tungsten Graphics, Inc
Moonlight: OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) 965GM 
Moonlight: OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 8.0.4
Mono.MoonException: invalid RuntimeVersion
at System.Windows.Deployment.CompareRuntimeVersions () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Windows.Deployment.ReadManifest () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Windows.Deployment.InitializeDeployment (IntPtr plugin, System.String xapPath,   System.String culture, System.String uiCulture) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
Moonlight: ErrorEventArgs created with message: 'invalid RuntimeVersion'
EMIT OF EVENT Error(1) ON OBJECT Surface CALLED WITH NO LISTENERS AND NON-NULL CALLDATA
```

The system is currently running Fedora Core 17, Mozilla Version 15.0.1, and Google Chrome 23.0.1271.64.  The system is 64 bit and as such I am using the 64 bit Moonlight extension, which is at version 3.99.0.3.  I apologize in advance if there is already an answer somewhere on the web that I have not been able to find yet.

Answer (score 0):

Well I have the same problem here...
The problem is that moonlight 3.99.0.3 doesn't support deployment of applications compiled with silverlight 5.0.61118.0 (you can check this downloading the xap file from the url in your log http://viaplay.se/assets/54bde6d6/ViasatPlayer.xap and checking AppManifest.xaml)